# Vectorization Octave

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization, octave

I am struggling with some basic vectorization operations in Octave.

Lets say I instantiate a 10*10 matrix A. 
`A = magic(10)`
I also instantiate a vector x. `x = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10]`

I want to use a vectorized operation, instead of for loops to fill in an empty vector e. 
`e = zeros(10,1)`

```
for i = 1:10
  for j = 1:10
    v(i) = v(i) + A(i, j) * x(j);
  end
end
```

I have studied the the octave documentation chapter 19 about vectorization, and I believe that the only answer is `v = A * x`. But I am unsure, whether other options exist to vectorize this loop.

Comment: What is wrong with `v = A * x`? Looks like a perfect solution.

Comment: Sure, but I am right that it would be the only solution ? As per octave documentation, it would be.

Comment: There's also `sum(A.*x.', 2)`, which uses element-wise multiplication with [broadcasting](https://octave.org/doc/v5.2.0/Broadcasting.html). But matrix multiplication is likely to be a little faster, and it looks cleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using multiplication is the best option, but there are other options, for example:

```
sum(A.*x.',2)
```

You often find such solutions when it comes to vectorizing loops like:

```
for i = 1:10
  for j = 1:10
    v(i) = v(i) + f(i,j);
  end
end
```

The intermediate step is a matrix which holds all solutions for f(i,j) (`sum(A.*x.',2)` in your example), then you accumulate replacing the `+` with a `sum`.